# How to check key press multiple times in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a cubing timer. When I press & hold Space, timer should become green. When I release, timer should start running. When I press again, timer should stop. And then all of this should happen again.

I need to check if:

1. **Space bar was pressed.**
2. **Space bar was released.**
3. **Space bar was pressed again.**

I have this code:

```
var down = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        if(down) return;
        down = true;
        console.log('Waiting...')
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        down = false;
        console.log('Start')
    }
}, false);

// I need some Stop function here
```

The problem is that when I press space bar and then release it and press again, it runs 4 functions. But I need to run 3 different ones. And then I have to be able to do the same again.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you are trying to do, what you expect to see, and what you are actually seeing?

Comment: I'm trying to create a cubing timer. When I press & hold Space, timer should become green. When I release, timer should start running. When I press again, timer should stop. And then all of this should happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `KeyboardEvent::repeat` to check whether you have the first key down event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

Also note that `window.event` is deprecated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

So the logic is to use a finite state automata and switch between states on key presses. When the state is changed a function from the `transitions` object is called - put there you logic to execute on changing the state:

```js
let state = 'stopped';

const transitions = {
  waiting: state => console.log(state),
  started: state => console.log(state),
  stopped: state => console.log(state),
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeState);
document.addEventListener('keyup', changeState);

function changeState({code, repeat, type: action}){

  if(code !== 'Space' || repeat){
    return;
  }
  
  // this allows to have more event types and states in the future without cluttering
  const actions = {
    keydown: () => state === 'stopped' ? 'waiting' : 'stopped',
    keyup: () => state === 'stopped' ? state : 'started',
  };
  
  // determine the next state 
  const next = actions[action]();
  // if the next state is different, commit it to the current and execute transition
  next === state || transitions[state = next](state);
  
}
```

Comment: It does the same thing actually. Let me explain in another way: I need 3 functions. One for waiting mode. Second for running some function (Start). Third for stopping the function. When I press once, First function runs. When I release, Start function runs. When I press again, Stop function runs. Can you help with that?

Comment: @TimurArazmedov fixed and improved

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I insert my functions?

Comment: @TimurArazmedov removed unneeded `if`. you could also upvote my answer (the arrow up) so i would be rewarded with extra 10 points and motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: @TimurArazmedov added `transitions` object where you can put your functions

Comment: @TimurArazmedov improved the code allowing to have the state logic without `if`s. it could be more complex to understand but more laconic and flexible